# There has been an error processing your request

Tags: php

when i click the remove item in mini cart of my magento site  it shows the following error.

Invalid form key

Help me to find  solution.

Comment: can you post screenshot of the error and inform which version of magento ?

Comment: you will get report error file "magento root directory/var/record" folder

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Magento require forms to have

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

to prevent CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) attacks.